# Word: in-text citing abbreviation is in wrong language. How to change it?

Tags: microsoft-word, citations, bibliography

I am using APA citing style for my research, but I am having some troubles with the citing.

The language of my Microsoft Word is set to English (UK) but when I cite in-text with the page number, instead of writing p. it says S. (Seite means page in German). 
I do not know why this happens and how I could change this.

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

I have already found the solution. The language for my sources were set to default, not to English.

To achieve this as seen on [Microsoft Community Forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other-mso_2010/word-2010-change-referencescitation-language/f67a4daf-2af2-40ba-a03c-d28596560e3e)

1. In the References tab, click Manage Sources.
2. Select a source in the Master List column.
3. Click the Edit button, which opens the Edit Source dialogue.
4. Click the Language box at the top right of the dialogue and choose the language.
5. Click OK.